# Vagrant - No guest IP was given to the Vagrant core NFS helper

Tags: windows-10, vagrant, virtualbox, ubuntu-16.04

Recently our Vagrant DEV VM's will no longer boot on virtualbox (windows 10).

Is this related to the current kernel bug that is causing issues with a lot of the distributions?

**BUG:** https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-meta-lts-xenial/+bug/1820526
**BUG:** https://bugs.launchpad.net/vagrant/+bug/1821083

Here is the launch code:

---

`vagrant up`

```
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: LOCAL-DEV_20190322_113839
==> default: Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
    default: Adapter 2: hostonly
==> default: You are trying to forward to privileged ports (ports <= 1024). Most
==> default: operating systems restrict this to only privileged process (typically
==> default: processes running as an administrative user). This is a warning in case
==> default: the port forwarding doesn't work. If any problems occur, please try a
==> default: port higher than 1024.
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 22 (guest) => 22 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 80 (guest) => 80 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 443 (guest) => 443 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3306 (guest) => 3306 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 6379 (guest) => 6379 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 4369 (guest) => 4369 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 9090 (guest) => 9090 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 9100 (guest) => 9100 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 9104 (guest) => 9104 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 9150 (guest) => 9150 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5672 (guest) => 5672 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8883 (guest) => 8883 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 15672 (guest) => 15672 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 15674 (guest) => 15674 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 15675 (guest) => 15675 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 25672 (guest) => 25672 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 35197 (guest) => 35197 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 1883 (guest) => 1883 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5673 (guest) => 5673 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 8161 (guest) => 8161 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 61613 (guest) => 61613 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 61614 (guest) => 61614 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 61616 (guest) => 61616 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 9900 (guest) => 9900 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 9910 (guest) => 9910 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 9200 (guest) => 9200 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 9300 (guest) => 9300 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5601 (guest) => 5601 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 27017 (guest) => 27017 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 27018 (guest) => 27018 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 27019 (guest) => 27019 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 27080 (guest) => 27080 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 28017 (guest) => 28017 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5432 (guest) => 5432 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5480 (guest) => 5480 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 10000 (guest) => 10000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 20000 (guest) => 20000 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 4444 (guest) => 4444 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 3128 (guest) => 3128 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: SSH address: 127.0.0.1:2222
    default: SSH username: vagrant
    default: SSH auth method: password
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection aborted. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Connection reset. Retrying...
==> default: Machine booted and ready!
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.2.16
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.2.26
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
[default] GuestAdditions seems to be installed (5.2.26) correctly, but not running.
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.2.16
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.2.26
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
Job for vboxadd-service.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status vboxadd-service.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.2.16
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.2.26
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.2.16
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.2.26
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
No guest IP was given to the Vagrant core NFS helper. This is an
internal error that should be reported as a bug.
```

---

`cat /etc/lsb-release`

```
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=16.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=xenial
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS"
```

---

`uname -r`

```
4.4.0-143-generic
```

---

I have attempted to rebuild the kernel headers. They seemed to install correctly.

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure virtualbox-dkms`

```
-------- Uninstall Beginning --------
Module:  virtualbox
Version: 5.1.38
Kernel:  4.4.0-143-generic (x86_64)
-------------------------------------

Status: Before uninstall, this module version was ACTIVE on this kernel.

vboxdrv.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-143-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetadp.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-143-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxnetflt.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-143-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.


vboxpci.ko:
 - Uninstallation
   - Deleting from: /lib/modules/4.4.0-143-generic/updates/dkms/
 - Original module
   - No original module was found for this module on this kernel.
   - Use the dkms install command to reinstall any previous module version.

depmod....

DKMS: uninstall completed.

------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.1.38
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Loading new virtualbox-5.1.38 DKMS files...
Building only for 4.4.0-143-generic
Building initial module for 4.4.0-143-generic
Done.

vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-143-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-143-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-143-generic/updates/dkms/

vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
 - Original module
   - No original module exists within this kernel
 - Installation
   - Installing to /lib/modules/4.4.0-143-generic/updates/dkms/

depmod.....

DKMS: install completed.
```

---

I also updated the `virtualbox` on Ubuntu

`sudo apt install virtualbox-5.2`

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libsdl-ttf2.0-0
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  virtualbox virtualbox-guest-additions-iso virtualbox-qt
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  libsdl-ttf2.0-0 virtualbox-5.2
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 3 to remove and 4 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/73.9 MB of archives.
After this operation, 28.8 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 375081 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing virtualbox-qt (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3) ...
Removing virtualbox (5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3) ...
Removing virtualbox-guest-additions-iso (5.1.38-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Selecting previously unselected package libsdl-ttf2.0-0:amd64.
(Reading database ... 374771 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libsdl-ttf2.0-0_2.0.11-3_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libsdl-ttf2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.11-3) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-5.2.
Preparing to unpack .../virtualbox-5.2_5.2.26-128414~Ubuntu~xenial_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking virtualbox-5.2 (5.2.26-128414~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
Processing triggers for systemd (229-4ubuntu21.17) ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead (0.100.0-19) ...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1.1) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.2) ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libsdl-ttf2.0-0:amd64 (2.0.11-3) ...
Setting up virtualbox-5.2 (5.2.26-128414~Ubuntu~xenial) ...
addgroup: The group `vboxusers' already exists as a system group. Exiting.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu11) ...
```

---

Command exists and doesn't throw any errors.

`sudo /sbin/vboxconfig`

```
vboxdrv.sh: Stopping VirtualBox services.
vboxdrv.sh: Starting VirtualBox services.
```

I'm stumped, maybe I will have to wait for a new kernel patch?

Comment: Even trying to mount a shared drive inside the VM is throwing errors.  

`sudo mount -t vboxsf development '/development'`
`/sbin/mount.vboxsf: mounting failed with the error: Protocol error`

Comment: Attempting to upgrade to the latest version of `vagrant v2.2.4` and `virtualbox v6.0.4 r128413 (Qt5.6.2)`.

Comment: No dice... `No guest IP was given to the Vagrant core NFS helper. This is an
internal error that should be reported as a bug.`

Comment: There is more information in: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1126591/virtualbox-error-after-last-ubuntu-software-update

It seems like it's a known problem that a lot of people have had, one way or another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't a quick and simple fix for this, your best bet is to downgrade the kernel version.

Get a list of kernels headers and images

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-header
dpkg --list | grep linux-image
```

Remove the offending kernel

```
sudo apt purge linux-image-4.4.0-143-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-143-generic linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-143-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-143-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-143-generic
```

`apt-mark` - hold the offending kernel for future updates

```
sudo apt-mark hold linux-image-4.4.0-143-generic linux-headers-4.4.0-143-generic linux-image-unsigned-4.4.0-143-generic linux-modules-4.4.0-143-generic linux-modules-extra-4.4.0-143-generic
sudo apt-mark showhold
```

Remove other kernels and `dkms`

```
sudo apt-get remove dkms build-essential linux-headers-*
```

Reinstall the older kernel and configure `dkms` using `virtualbox-guest-dkms`

```
sudo apt-get install dkms build-essential linux-headers-4.4.0-142-generic virtualbox-guest-dkms
```

Reboot to enable the old kernel version

```
sudo reboot
```

Run `apt update`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade -y
```

And you should be able to launch your `virtual-box` / `vagrant` boxes again.

Answer (score 0):

I pushed a fix some days ago, and today it migrated in release.
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/4.3.40-dfsg-0ubuntu14.04.1
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox-lts-xenial/4.3.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.14.04.1~14.04.1
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox-guest-additions-iso/4.3.40-0ubuntu1.14.04.1
please use the fixed package.

Comment: This is for Ubuntu 14.04 (Trusy). Are there plans for a Ubuntu 16.04 (Xenial) patch?

Comment: Fox Xenial,  virtualbox 5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.3  and virtualbox-hwe 5.1.38-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 should do the trick